# How to iterate over dataframe multiple columns in pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

So, lets say I have a dataframe df with one single column,  where `df.show()` is
|a,b,c,d,....|
|a,b,c,d,....|
so I want to get a df1, where `df1.show()` is
|a|b|c.....|
 so to put it shortly I want to break a dataframe with one single column into a dataframe with multiple columns. So, I get the idea of

```
split_col = pyspark.sql.functions.split(df['x'], ' '),
df=df.withColumn('0',split_col.getItem(0))
df=df.withColumn('1',split_col.getItem(1))
```

, so on
but if I have tons of columns. Is there any way to do this in pyspark except for huge iteration over this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So you could **`iterate and set name`** using the **`select clause`** as shown below:

In this one you will be **`hitting split`** every time the loop runs so it will be less efficient.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.select(*[(F.split("x",' ')[i]).alias(str(i)) for i in range(100)]).explain()

#== Physical Plan ==
#*(1) Project [split(x#200,  )[0] AS 0#1708, split(x#200,  )[1] 
AS 1#1709, split(x#200,  )[2] AS 2#1710, split(x#200,  )[3] AS 
3#1711, split(x#200,  )[4] AS 4#1712, split(x#200,  )[5] AS 
5#1713, split(x#200,  )[6] AS 6#1714, split(x#200,  )[7] AS 
7#1715, split(x#200,  )[8] AS 8#1716, split(x#200,  )[9] AS 
9#1717, split(x#200,  )[10] AS 10#1718, split(x#200,  )[11] AS 
11#1719, split(x#200,  )[12] AS 12#1720, split(x#200,  )[13] AS 
13#1721, split(x#200,  )[14] AS 14#1722, split(x#200,  )[15] AS 
15#1723, split(x#200,  )[16] AS 16#1724, split(x#200,  )[17] AS 
17#1725, split(x#200,  )[18] AS 18#1726, split(x#200,  )[19] AS 
19#1727, split(x#200,  )[20] AS 20#1728, split(x#200,  )[21] AS 
21#1729, split(x#200,  )[22] AS 22#1730, split(x#200,  )[23] AS 
23#1731, ... 76 more fields]
#+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[x#200]
```

Instead you could split it **`once`**, and allow spark to **`project`** only **`one split operation as opposed to many.`**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


df\
  .withColumn("x", F.split('x',' '))\
  .select(*[(F.col("x")[i]).alias(str(i)) for i in range(100)]).drop("x").explain()

#== Physical Plan ==
#*(1) Project [x#1908[0] AS 0#1910, x#1908[1] AS 1#1911, 
x#1908[2] AS 2#1912, x#1908[3] AS 3#1913, x#1908[4] AS 4#1914, 
x#1908[5] AS 5#1915, x#1908[6] AS 6#1916, x#1908[7] AS 7#1917, 
x#1908[8] AS 8#1918, x#1908[9] AS 9#1919, x#1908[10] AS 10#1920, 
x#1908[11] AS 11#1921, x#1908[12] AS 12#1922, x#1908[13] AS 
13#1923, x#1908[14] AS 14#1924, x#1908[15] AS 15#1925, x#1908[16] 
AS 16#1926, x#1908[17] AS 17#1927, x#1908[18] AS 18#1928, 
x#1908[19] AS 19#1929, x#1908[20] AS 20#1930, x#1908[21] AS 
21#1931, x#1908[22] AS 22#1932, x#1908[23] AS 23#1933, ... 76 
more fields]
+- *(1) Project [split(x#200,  ) AS x#1908]
   +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[x#200]
```